# Rest controller method that accepts text/uri-list

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

Lets say I've got a many-to-many relationship between the entities Student and Course, and I have a separate StudentCourses entity that maps the join.

It'd be nice to be able to assign a course to a student by PATCH-ing /courses/1 (text/uri-list) to students/1/courses, but that doesn't work because it's expecting a reference to a StudentCourse entity instead.

Are these my only alternatives?

1. Force the client to create a StudentCourse resource first, and then patch that uri to /cstudents/1/studentcourses..?
2. Write my own controller method for handling PATCH text/uri-list to students/1/courses. (I can't figure out how to do this.)

Comment: Sounds like you have attempted some coding on this, i recommend you paste it in, as it will help the community see better what you are trying to accomplish and may have fixes for it.